# haproxy configure Authentication and ACL

Tags: authentication, acl, haproxy

I'm new on the world of load balancing...
I heard about HAProxy and I wonder if I can achieve this objective (not found yet over searches already done):

1. HAProxy receive a MQTT/HTTP connection with basic authentication
   (login-password) or token based
2. HAProxy checks credentials from a Database (or
   LDAP)
3. HAProxy manage the access depending on the authenticated User.

--> all of user/credential and ACL should be stored in Database.

Is this possible? Is there in HAProxy a system of custom plugin/add-on to enhance its behavior ?

I found things about settings list of ACL directly in the configuration with already existing list of login/password (but not dynamically even if cached after)

Thanks a lot for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only supported in Enterprise Haproxy:

> The HAProxy Single Sign-On solution [...] is also compatible with Microsoft Active Directory or OpenLDAP servers.

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-8r1/security/using-sso/

The only plugin I found is a http request check to see if user is authenticated on an arbitrary endpoint:

https://github.com/TimWolla/haproxy-auth-request

But it requires a specialized web app responding the requests for that.